# CodeIgniter and validation of multi-dimensional form element names

Tags: php, codeigniter

Lets say I have an HTML form which shows groups, and in each group I have a name and multiple users.  The following is a sample HTML structure, simplified to contain the relevant elements only:

```
Group Name: <input name='group[0][name]' />
User 1: <input name='group[0][users][0]' />
User 2: <input name='group[0][users][0]' />
User 3: <input name='group[0][users][0]' />
<hr />
Group Name: <input name='group[1][name]' />
User 1: <input name='group[1][users][0]' />
User 2: <input name='group[1][users][0]' />
User 3: <input name='group[1][users][0]' />
```

I read the entire structure into CodeIgniter using `$this->input->post('group');` and life is good.

I want to add form verification with a custom function. If I do this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('group[]', 'Group', 'callback_verifyGroupData');
```

my `verifyGroupData($group_data)` function is called once for each group. In this example, it is called twice, each time having the group data passed in. Here is the dummy function for now:

```
function verifyGroupData($data) {
    log_message('info','KRYSTODO: verifyGroupData data ' . print_r($data,true));
    $this->form_validation->set_message('verifyGroupData', 'This is not entirely checked yet.');
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that I need to be able to show errors separately for each group. Right now, when I want to add an individual error display in my HTML view, I do:

```
<?php if(form_error('group[]')) { 
        echo '<div class="validationError">' . form_error('group[]') . '</div>'; 
    }?>
```

The issue is this code does not differentiate between an error set for group[0] vs. group[1].

According to the CodeIgniter documentation, I should be able to do this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('group[0]', 'Group', 'callback_verifyGroupData');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('group[1]', 'Group', 'callback_verifyGroupData');
```

In practice, this does not result in my `verifyGroupData()` getting called at all.

Can you offer an approach to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the form_validation library itself to try and find out what's going on? It's in system/libraries/form_validation.

Answer (score 0):

This might be worth a try...
Change your rules to:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('group[0][]', 'Group','callback_verifyGroupData');
```

And the same for the second group. Note the extra brackets in the field name.
Haven't had a chance to test it I'm afraid, but it's worth a quick try! :-)

Comment: I have given this a try as well. Unfortunately, no-go. Thank you for the suggestion.